# How to extract a single row from a 2D vector and assign to a 1D vector?

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array

Consider the following code:

```
  vector < vector <double > > xor_input;
  xor_input.resize ( 6 );
  for (int i = 0; i < xor_input.size(); i++){
    xor_input[i].resize( 100 );
  }

  xor_input.resize( 6 );
  for(int i = 0; i < xor_input.size(); i++){
    xor_input[i].resize( 100 );
    for( int j = 0; j < xor_input[i].size(); j++){
      xor_input[i][j] = image_load[i][j];
    }
  }

  vector < double >  xor_output;
  xor_output.resize( 6 );  
  for(int i = 0; i < xor_output.size(); i++){
      xor_output[i] = xor_input[i];
    }
```

I am loading 6 images to the 2D vector  (xor_input). 
I need to store a single row (which is an image) from a 2D vector (xor_input) to a 1D vector (xor_output).

The xor_output should contain the exact image as loaded from xor_input 2D vector for further comparison.

Problem is that xor_output is a 1D vector and xor_input is a 2D vector and i need to store the single row into xor_ouput from xor_input.

I am getting the following error:

```
error: cannot convert ‘__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<std::vector<double> > >::value_type {aka std::vector<double>}’ to ‘__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<double> >::value_type {aka double}’ in assignment
       xor_output[i] = xor_input[i];
                     ^
```

Comment: The answer to the title would be `xor_output = xor_input[index];`, but the description is unclear.

Comment: Which of your 600 double values input shall be the 6 double values of your output? The first in each vector? The second? The `k`th ... `xor_output[i] = xor_input[i][k];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
xor_output[i] = xor_input[i];
```

1) xor_output[i] is a double. <--Not what you want

2) xor_input[i] is an array of doubles.

3) xor_output is, also, an array of doubles <-- This is what you want.

```
xor_output = xor_input[i];
```

Would call the vector's operator= to copy, not extract, values from the right-operand-vector to the left-operand-vector.

In short, your left hand operand is a single double rather than your expected vector.